# How to prevent Dart xml package to decode entity?

Tags: xml, dart

Having the following xml file :

```
<sense>
<pos>&int;</pos>
</sense>
```

The following code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void main() {
  File('data/sense.xml').readAsString().then((String contents) {   
    xml.XmlDocument document = xml.parse(contents);
    xml.XmlElement sense = document.findAllElements('sense').first;
    print(sense.toString());
  });
}
```

will output

```
<sense>
<pos>∫</pos>
</sense>
```

Are there any option to prevent the entity `&int;` to be decoded to `∫` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the decoded entities is not currently supported by the library. I suggest that you file a feature request at https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml.

As a workaround you could wrap your entities in CDATA tokens, so that your input would look like:

```xml
<sense>
<pos><![CDATA[&int;]]></pos>
</sense>
```

Comment: Seems it is now fixed since the latest version according to the changelog https://pub.dev/packages/xml#-changelog-tab-

Comment: Yes, this has been fixed in the meantime: `xml.parse(input, entityMapping: xml.XmlNullEntityMapping())` prevents any entity decoding.